# when I read the documentation of the react, I am confused by the following words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

[image: react]

I'm confused with these words :

> if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering

Answer (score 0):

The key part is where it says that a problem with it is that a callback is created every time the LoggingButton renders. 
 Say a child component was created like:

MyButton onClick={ (e) => this.handleClick.bind(this)}

I'm that case if LoggingButton rerenders, MyButton will render too becasue the reference to this.handleClick that was created anonymously will be destroyed.

Alternatively if the function is bound in the constructor the reference will not be destroyed if Logging Button rerenders so MyButton will not render again.

Where you really dont want to do the arrow function is in a loop.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "will render too"? render() function be called? if we don't pass any props that function wont be called?